# reactJS | antd | Facing issue in sustaining selection on re-rendering page after selection of dropdown - which triggers a dispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, antd

I am trying to dispatch an action onSelect of a component to populate another dropdown. I have used onSelect event-handler to achieve that instead of onFieldsChange option of antd, since I need to use a local variable that will not be available in the onFieldsChange callback scope.

But the result is - after dispatch is called and component gets re-rendered, the dropdown element gets cleared of its selected value, and gets reset to its initialValue. I am not able to retain the selection. Below is the code snippet -

```js
                    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={item.label}>
                        {getFieldDecorator(item.id, {
                           rules: [
                                { required: required, message: errorText },
                            ],
                            initialValue: initVal,
                            trigger: 'onSelect',
                        })(
                            <Select style={{ width: '100%' }} onSelect={self.handleChange.bind(self,item)}>
                                { options }
                            </Select>
                        )}
                    </FormItem>
```

Here is the handleChange callback onSelect -

```js
    public handleChange(item, val) {
        console.log(item);
        console.log('Current Value: ' + val);
        let url = item.hasOwnProperty('urlOnSelect') ? item.urlOnSelect : null;
        if (!url) {
            return;
        }

        let params = item.hasOwnProperty('queryParams_S') ? item.queryParams_S : null;
        let value;

        if (params) {
            url = url + '?';
            params.map(function(param) {
                value = val;
                if (url.indexOf('?') !== (url.length - 1)) {
                    url = url + '&';
                }
                url = url + param.paramName + '=' + value;
            });
        }
        let fieldsToPopulateOnSelect = item.hasOwnProperty('fieldsToPopulateOnSelect') ? item.fieldsToPopulateOnSelect : null;
        this.props.dispatch(fetchUrlOnSelect(this.profileKey, url, fieldsToPopulateOnSelect));
        this.props.form.setFields({
            [item.id]: {
            value: val,
            },
        });
    }
```

Note: As seen above, I have even tried to use setFields property to set the value just after dispatch! But still the dropdown component gets cleared on re-render!

Please help!!!! :|

Answer (score 0):

by "the dropdown element gets cleared of its selected value" do you mean the original dropdown or the new dropdown (the one that is being filled?)

I dont think you need to do

```
this.props.form.setFields({
            [item.id]: {
            value: val,
            },
        });
```

since it's handled by antd, see this example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRwyaa?editors=0010

Comment: by "the dropdown element gets cleared of its selected value" I meant the original selection gets cleared.. the problem doesnot come if there is a single dropdown being selected. The selection gets cleared when I dispatch an action on selection, which inturn results in component re-render, (that clears the selected value).

Comment: how about create a demo project

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default class UserRemoteSelect extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      fetchType: PropTypes.string,
      token: PropTypes.string,
      defaultValue: PropTypes.object,
      onSelect: PropTypes.func,
      selectedValue: PropTypes.string
    }

    async componentDidMount () {
      this.fetchOptions()
    }

  state = {
    data: [],
    fetching: true
  };

  fetchOptions = async () => {
    if (!this.state.data.length) {
      const { fetchType, token } = this.props
      const header = { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
      const route = getLocationRoute(fetchType)
      const response = await RequestObject.GetRequest(route, {}, header)
      this.setState({ data: response.data, fetching: false })
    }
  };

  render () {
    const { fetching, data } = this.state
    const { fetchType, onSelect, selectedValue } = this.props
    const id = `${fetchType}_id`
    const val = `${fetchType}_name`

    return (
      <Select
        labelInValue
        placeholder="Select Regions"
        showSearch
        notFoundContent={fetching ? <Spin size="small" /> : 'no result found'}
        filterOption={(input, option) =>
          option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        }
        defaultValue={selectedValue}
        onChange={ onSelect }
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
      >
        {data.map(d => (
          <Option key={d[id]}>{d[val]}</Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    )
  }
}
// Use above component in Main form like this
getFieldDecorator('parentId', {
    rules: [{ required: true, message: `Please enter ${selectFetchType} name` }],
    initialValue: ''
})(<Select 
      fetchType={selectFetchType} 
      token={ token }
      onSelect={ this.onSelect }
      selectedValue={
      { key: initialValues['selected'],
        label: initialValues['selectValue'] 
      }
    } />
)
```

You need to create separate 'Select' component which fetches the data from api and updated options. Example